# The minhag to read chapter 119 in Tehilim in Chanuka (Temney Api)

Tags: minhag, chanuka, tehilim-psalms

I heard that there is a minhag to read Chapter 119 in Tehilim (Psalms) every Chanuka Evening (Temney Api the name of the chapter). I also heard that each evening there are 4 letters of the chapter to be read. What is the seder (order) of the reading from this chapter per night?

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Elimelech Biderman shlita mentions it in this week's edition of his [Torah Wellspring - Parshas Vayeishev 5874](https://www.torahlectures.org/post/torah-wellsprings-rabbi-biderman-shlit-a-vayeishev-chanukah-5784). On p.15 he writes that some say chapter 119 in Tehillim because it is full of requests for success in Torah and mitzvos.

In footnote 13 it writes:

> The Leket Yoshar (p.43) writes that his rebbe, the Terumas HaDeshen, would say chapter קי"ט in Tehillim every day. Indeed, it is an excellent time to say it while looking at the Chanukah lecht, which is mesugal for success in Torah.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dov, there is a Belza minhag to read each day 4 letters from the chapter. Can you add the order of the letters according to their minhag?